# Query: employees who do not have the same name

Tags: sql

Given the following data:

```
EMPID   NAME    SALARY  DID
1       kevin   32000   2
2       joan    42000   1
3       brian   37000   3
4       larry   82000   5
5       harry   92000   4
6       peter   45000   2
7       peter   68000   3
8       smith   39000   4
9       chen    71000   1
10      kim     46000   5
11      smith   46000   1
```

List the name of employees who do not share the same name.

I'm not sure if I have to join the table with itself (or do something else).

This is what I wrote so far:

```
SELECT distinct e.name
FROM employee e, employee ee
WHERE e.name <> ee.name
```

Comment: what output are you looking for? why is `SELECT distinct e.name FROM employee e` not sufficient?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. Do you want to pull names that are not duplicated. As in names that are available in the table only once? Or as @njzk2 States, do you just want a distinct list of names...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for joining:

```
SELECT name
FROM employee
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) = 1
```

count how many of each name there are, then return only those where there's only one name. e.g.  peter has a count of 2 and won't show up, while kim has a count of 1 and WILL show up.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks for clearing up the confusion

Comment: Props on the answer. I had something else that would have worked, but much more code. I always forget having.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get just distinct names the following query should be enough:

```
SELECT distinct e.name
FROM employee e
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select * from employee;
+-------+-------+--------+-----+
| empid | name  | salary | did |
+-------+-------+--------+-----+
|     1 | kevin |  32000 |   2 |
|     2 | joan  |  42000 |   1 |
|     3 | brian |  37000 |   3 |
|     4 | larry |  82000 |   5 |
|     5 | harry |  92000 |   4 |
|     6 | peter |  45000 |   2 |
|     7 | peter |  68000 |   3 |
|     8 | smith |  39000 |   4 |
|     9 | chen  |  71000 |   1 |
|    10 | kim   |  46000 |   5 |
|    11 | smith |  46000 |   1 |
+-------+-------+--------+-----+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select distinct name from employee;
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| kevin |
| joan  |
| brian |
| larry |
| harry |
| peter |
| smith |
| chen  |
| kim   |
+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

With an inner join that does a count of the number of records for each emp. you can filter the results where count = 1

```
SELECT 
    T.EMPID,
    T.NAME,
    T.SALARY,
    T.DID 
FROM 
    employee  AS T 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT , NAME FROM employee  GROUP BY NAME) AS A ON T.NAME = A.NAME
WHERE 
    CNT = 1
```

Comment: MarkB is the best code to get the list, or using mine will dump the table with the data of each of those employees.